# Consumer Maximization Problem Doesn't Work in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear, scripting

I'm trying to solve a problem that can be seen in the paper "The Role of the Structural Transformation in Aggregate Productivity". The problem is:
[image]

Manually it is difficult to find the solution, but this problem has an analytical solution, and the solution is Real. So I'm using Wolfram Mathematica and I make the following code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*Define the utility function*)
Utility = 
  a*Log[ca - abar] + (1 - a)*(1/rho)*
    Log[b*cm^rho + (1 - b)*(cs + sbar)^rho];
(*Define constraint*)

constraint = pa*ca + pm*cm + ps*cs - w *l;
(*Define the Lagrangian and its derivatives*)
Lagrangian = Utility - \[Lambda]*constraint;

Foc1 = D[Lagrangian, ca];
Foc2 = D[Lagrangian, cm];
Foc3 = D[Lagrangian, cs];
Foc4 = D[Lagrangian, \[Lambda]];

sols = Simplify[
  Solve[{Foc1 == 0, Foc2 == 0, Foc3 == 0, Foc4 == 0}, {ca, cm, 
    cs, \[Lambda]},
   Assumptions -> {pa > 0, pm > 0, ps > 0,
      ca > 0, cm > 0, cs > 0,
      abar > 0, sbar > 0,
      w > 0, l > 0,
      0 < a < 1 , 0 < b < 1, rho < -1}
   ]]
```

However, he does not find a symbolic solution to my problem, the code crashes. So, I tried other ways, and write my problem without Lagrange. But it returns this in a few seconds with no warnings, no helpful messages and no solution.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*Definir a função de utilidade*)
Utility = 
  a*Log[ca - abar] + (1 - a)*(1/rho)*
    Log[b*cm^rho + (1 - b)*(cs + sbar)^rho];

(*Definir a restrição*)
constraint = pa*ca + pm*cm + ps*cs - w*l;

(*Definir o objetivo de maximização*)
Objective = -Utility;

(*Resolver o problema de maximização*)
Maximize[{Objective, 
  constraint > 0 && ca > 0 && cm > 0 && cs > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 && 
   0 < a < 1 && 0 < b < 1 && rho < -1, ca > abar}, {ca, cm, cs}]
```

The solution is real, but raising expressions to negative Real powers can causes problems? Is there something wrong in my code? What can I do to simplify or force Wolfram to find the solution?

Comment: Give us a link for the paper where is analytical solution?Thanks

Comment: For first code and for: `rho = -2` can be computed. Try: `rho = -2; eq = ({Foc1 == 0, Foc2 == 0, Foc3 == 0, Foc4 == 0} // 
   FullSimplify); Solve[eq, {ca, cm, cs, \[Lambda]}]` .

Comment: The paper can be view [here](https://www.scielo.br/j/rbe/a/HKjDqFvNSGtZRPDZgdtyrKx/?lang=pt). In appendix A3 the autors provide an analytical solution to this problem.

Comment: The author also wrote that these are systems of nonlinear equations, and such systems cannot be solved analytically, only numerically.

Comment: But in appendix the authors provide an analytical solution to this problem. Equations A-3, A-4 and A-5. In the paper "The Role of the Structural Transformation in Aggregate Productivity", in fact, they don't provide analytical solution, only some of FOCs.

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

For $f(x) > 0$

$$
\arg\max \log(f(x)) = \arg\max f(x)
$$

so try instead

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*Define the utility function*)
Utility = a*(ca - abar)^a (b*cm^rho + (1 - b)*(cs + sbar)^rho)^((1 - a)*(1/rho));
(*Define constraint*)

constraint = pa*ca + pm*cm + ps*cs - w*l;
(*Define the Lagrangian and its derivatives*)
Lagrangian = Utility - \[Lambda]*constraint;

Foc1 = D[Lagrangian, ca];
Foc2 = D[Lagrangian, cm];
Foc3 = D[Lagrangian, cs];
Foc4 = D[Lagrangian, \[Lambda]];

sols = Simplify[Solve[{Foc1 == 0, Foc2 == 0, Foc3 == 0, Foc4 == 0}, {ca, cm, cs, \[Lambda]}]]
```

Comment: The problem is that he doesn't find a solution to all the unknowns.

Comment: Substituting the found values for `ca` and `cm` into the constraint, we can conclude that one of `ca`, `cm`, `cs`, depends of the others.

Comment: This doesn't work well. He cannot find a feasible value for `cs`. The closest solution I found was the provide by @MariuszIwaniuk where `rho` equal to -2, but I replace by 2. `rho = 2; eq = ({Foc1 == 0, Foc2 == 0, Foc3 == 0, Foc4 == 0} //     FullSimplify); Solve[eq, {ca, cm, cs, \[Lambda]}]`.